# Unexpected result of a SQL query

Tags: sql

Can anyone explain why  this query:

```
SELECT employee_id, last_name, salary 
FROM   employees
WHERE  department_id IN (SELECT department_id
                     FROM   employees
                     WHERE  last_name LIKE '%u%'
                     )
AND  salary > (SELECT AVG(salary)  
           FROM employees);
```

returns way less rows than this nested one:

```
SELECT employee_id, last_name, salary 
FROM   employees
WHERE  department_id IN (SELECT department_id
                     FROM   employees
                     WHERE  last_name LIKE '%u%'
                     AND  salary > (SELECT AVG(salary)  
                                    FROM employees);
                     )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first returns all employees who meet the following conditions:

- The employee is in a department has a "u" employee.
- The employee has a salary larger than the average.

The second returns all employees who meet these conditions:

- The employee is in a department that has a "u" employee who has a salary larger than the average.

The two are very different conditions.  I wouldn't expect them to return the same result set.

Also, whenever you have more than one table in a query, you should use table aliases that are abbreviations of the table name *and* you should qualify all column names.

Comment: Thanks,a silly question I guess  ,I realized that now you've said it explicitly.

Comment: Wouldn't it be where the employees last name contains a "u"?

Comment: @TimothyG. . . . I was just shortening the description.

Comment: @ketflix please accept the answer if it's sufficent for you so others will now your problem is solved.

Comment: @AndréStannek the OP must wait 15 minutes before accepting an answer.